# OpenCV - How to fit a long curve to a short curved line?

Tags: c++, opencv, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a curve to a short curved line in an image. For example, if the line is like this (suppose this is a curved line, not a straight one):

[image]

I would like the result to be something like this (the red curve):

[image]

When I try `approxPoly` it becomes somewhat like this (before gaussian blurring):

[image]

I can smooth the image by blurring, but I still won't have the conttinious curve. Do I need to calculate an approximate equation for the curve or is there a simpler way?

Comment: `approxPoly` uses the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), which won't give you a mathematical function, just a set of points. Whether you use all of the points or just a few along the curve, you still need to use a method like [polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression) to get a continuous function that fits the curve.

Comment: Looking into it. I'll post here if I get to something